# What are the storage locations of the various types of Automator workflows

Tags: automator

The purpose of this question is to create a reference for the various default storage locations where Automator stores the files it creates and saves.

I've found a few from searching, but have yet to see a quick reference listing the possible storage locations for all the Automator workflow types. On OS X 10.6.8 with Automator 2.1.1 they are:

- Workflow
- Application
- Service
- Folder Action
- Print Plugin
- iCal Alarm
- Image Capture Plugin

Can anyone provide a list? (If you have lists for other OS/Automator versions, that would be a nice addition to the reference as well.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Tested this on 10.7.1, Automator 2.2.

- Workflow - for me this defaults to `~/Documents`, but these can be saved anywhere you like.
- Application - same as above. When saving a workflow/application for the first time, it even lets you change the type in the save dialog.
- Services - `~/Library/Services`
- Folder Action - The actual workflow is saved in `~/Library/Workflows/Applications/Folder Actions`. When creating the folder action, it asks for a folder to 'attach' to in the dropdown at the top. The actions will apply to the folder you choose here.
- Print Plugin - `~/Library/PDF Services`
- iCal Alarm - `~/Library/Workflows/Applications/iCal`
- Image Capture Plugin - `~/Library/Workflows/Applications/Image Capture`

Easy way to find this out in case you forget - after creating/saving one of the types that doesn't prompt you right away for a save location, right click the proxy icon in the title bar to see the path:

[image]

Comment: Fantastic tip on the right click for the path. For OSX 10.6.8 with Automator 2.1.1, all the paths you listed are the same. (Note that the Workflow and Application save dialog defaults to the last place one of the respective workflows was saved for me.) Thanks much.